# Import node from one XML to another on PowerShell

Tags: xml, powershell

I need to copy node with name "ProjectOptions" from default.xml to original.xml without modifying anything else:

Original.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<KEYS>
  <KEY ObjectName="computername_user" RegObjectType="0">
    <KEYS>
      <KEY ObjectName="Desktop" RegObjectType="0">
        <KEYS>
          <KEY ObjectName="Settings" RegObjectType="0">
            <KEYS>
              <KEY ObjectName="PrinterDefault" RegObjectType="0">
                <VALUES>
                  <VALUE ObjectName="PrinterOrientation" Value="2" ValueType="4" />
                </VALUES>
              </KEY>
              <KEY ObjectName="ProjectOptions" RegObjectType="0">
                <VALUES>
                  <VALUE ObjectName="ShowWelcomeMsg" Value="0" ValueType="4" />
                </VALUES>
              </KEY>
            </KEYS>
          </KEY>
        </KEYS>
      </KEY>
    </KEYS>
  </KEY>
</KEYS>
```

Default.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no" ?>
<KEYS>
  <KEY ObjectName="computername_user" RegObjectType="0">
    <KEYS>
      <KEY ObjectName="Desktop" RegObjectType="0">
        <KEYS>
          <KEY ObjectName="Settings" RegObjectType="0">
            <KEYS>
              <KEY ObjectName="PrinterDefault" RegObjectType="0">
                <VALUES>
                  <VALUE ObjectName="PrinterOrientation" Value="2" ValueType="4"/>
                </VALUES>
              </KEY>
              <KEY ObjectName="ProjectOptions" RegObjectType="0">
                <VALUES>
                  <VALUE ObjectName="GSAddBatchOptionDialogRect" Value="381,203,981,629" ValueType="2"/>
                  <VALUE ObjectName="GSHeadNodeName" Value="" ValueType="2"/>
                  <VALUE ObjectName="GSIsAdvancedMode" Value="1" ValueType="4"/>
                  <VALUE ObjectName="GSRemoteSchedulerPlatform" Value="" ValueType="2"/>
                  <VALUE ObjectName="GSSchedulerName" Value="" ValueType="2"/>
                  <VALUE ObjectName="GSShowFrequentlyUsedBatchOptions" Value="1" ValueType="4"/>
                  <VALUE ObjectName="GSUserName" Value="" ValueType="2"/>
                  <VALUE ObjectName="ShowWelcomeMsg" Value="0" ValueType="4"/>
                </VALUES>
              </KEY>
            </KEYS>
          </KEY>
        </KEYS>
      </KEY>
    </KEYS>
  </KEY>
</KEYS>
```

I tried something like this

```
$xml = [xml](Get-Content "C:\Temp\original.xml")
$xmld = [xml](Get-Content "C:\Temp\default.xml")
$Child=$xml.KEYS.KEY.KEYS.KEY.KEYS.KEY.KEYS.KEY[1].VALUES.VALUE
$xml.DocumentElement.InsertAfter($XML.ImportNode($xmld.SelectSingleNode("//KEY[@ObjectName = 'ProjectOptions']"), $true), $Child)
$xml.Save("C:\Temp\save.xml")
```

But it ended with "The reference node is not a child of this node."
Please tell me where I went wrong.
Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You try to insert the imported node under the `DocumentElement` node, but `$Child` is not a direct child element of that node. You need to call the `InsertAfter()` method on the parent node of `$Child`.

Change this:

```
$xml.DocumentElement.InsertAfter($XML.ImportNode($xmld.SelectSingleNode("//KEY[@ObjectName = 'ProjectOptions']"), $true), $Child)
```

into this:

```
$Child.ParentNode.InsertAfter($XML.ImportNode($xmld.SelectSingleNode("//KEY[@ObjectName='ProjectOptions']"), $true), $Child)
```

and the problem will disappear.

---

As a side note, you may want to use an XPath expression instead of dot-notation for selecting `$Child`:

```
$Child = $xml.SelectSingleNode('//VALUE[@ObjectName="ShowWelcomeMsg"]')
```

Answer (score 2):

Found a simple way:

```
$xmlPO = $xml.SelectNodes("//KEY[@ObjectName='ProjectOptions']")
$xmldPO = $xmld.SelectNodes("//KEY[@ObjectName='ProjectOptions']")
$xmlPO.set_InnerXML($xmldPO.innerXML)
$xml.Save($dpath)​
```